# Do I need to explicitly start and end transactions in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and have the following setup:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Dog {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
 }


public class PersonDao {

public Long createPetRelation(String ownerName, String dogName) {

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

     Dog dog = new Dog();
     dog.setName("Fido");
     Person person = new Person();
     person.setName("Joe");
     person.addDog(dog);
     entityManager.persist(person);

     return person.getId();
  }
}
```

I'm wondering whether I need to wrap the persistence code in a transaction or whether Hibernate can figure out based on the `@OneToMany` relationship that if the saving of the Dog entities fails then the whole thing should be rolled back? It's not clear from the documentation.

I'm not using a container or framework, just straight up Hibernate in a standalone Java project with JPA configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to wrap the code in the transaction. Like JPA that Hibernate implement, it not automatically create transaction when you run operation that modify the database. But if you use java spefication like EJB, you don't need to explicitly create transaction because by default, all ejb methods are transactional. If you use framework like Spring, you can simply make your method transactional.